# Powershell find multiple files from multiple remote computers, from all drives

Tags: powershell, foreach, get-childitem

Needed to make a script that finds a list of files from a list of multiple computers. The script below works fine for that. 
Now would need to add a functionality so that script goes thru *ALL* drives per computer, not just C$. Problem is I don't know which computers have which drives..

The current script:

```
$computers = Get-Content .\computers.txt

$filenames = Get-Content .\filenamelist.txt

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    foreach ($filename in $filenames) {
        Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force \\$computer\c$ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
        Where-Object { ($_.PSIsContainer -eq $false) -and ( $_.Name -eq "$filename") } |
        Select-Object Name, Directory | 
        Export-Csv .\FoundFiles.csv -nti -append
    }
}
```

So I should somehow implement command line:

```
$Drives = Get-PSDrive -PSProvider 'FileSystem'
```

So that it gets run on each computer and the Get-ChildItem line run based on the result, for each existing drive on each remote computer.

Any ideas please?

Comment: You will search each hard drive of the target computer for each single file you have in your 'filenamelist.txt' again and again and again. That might not be the most efficient way and quite stressful for the single computer. Especially whan you do it with UNC-Path. ;-) You should urgently consider using PSRemoting.

Comment: To get all fixed disks on a computer you can use `Get-CimInstance -ClassName CIM_LogicalDisk | Where-Object -Property DriveType -EQ -Value 3 `

Comment: PLEASE, wrap your code in code formatting. the instructions are linked on the page you used to create your Question ... [*grin*]

Comment: this page >>> How to Query the Windows Search Index using SQL and PowerShell — https://www.petri.com/how-to-query-the-windows-search-index-using-sql-and-powershell <<< shows [at the end] how to access the windows search index from PoSh. that seems likely to be far faster than G-CI will ever be. [*grin*] it that is not available for all your drives, then i would use robocopy set to "log only" to get the full list & then search that.